# Replace vector3 list with object list?

Tags: unity, vector

In this script I respawn a group of enemies in different places. To choose those places I have to put manually position value. I need to change this with object.

```
    [SerializeField]
List<SpawnEnemy> objectsToSpawn;

void Update()
{

    for (int i = objectsToSpawn.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
    {
        SpawnEnemy so = objectsToSpawn[i];
        so.TimeCount += Time.deltaTime;
        if (so.TimeCount >= so.time)
        {
            so.TimeCount -= so.time;
            Instantiate(so.star, so.spawnLocation[0], Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }

}
}

[System.Serializable]
class SpawnEnemy
{
 public GameObject star = null;
 public float time = 1;
 public float TimeCount = 0;
 public Vector3[] spawnLocation; // change from vecrtor3 to gameobject or transform
}
```

Comment: So what is stopping you from changing the type ?

Answer (score 1):

I solved. Just change...

```
public Vector3[] spawnLocation;
```

to

```
public Transform[] spawnLocation;
```

and then you can Instantiate using..

```
 Instantiate(so.star, so.spawnLocation[0].transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
```

Done...
Thank you.

Comment: `so.spawnLocation[0].transform.position` the object you get is already a transform `so.spawnLocation[0].position` should suffice